# Custom Membership Provider with Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm a little new to ASP.NET and I want to create a web site with ASP.NET MVC 4  where I have 4 Areas : Member Area , Admin Area, User Area and a Agency Area. The problem is that I want to make an authentification system for these 4 Areas, I have read about Custom Membership Providers and I made one of my own. But what I didn't understand is how can we work with Areas in a context of a Custom Membership Provider? Is there any way to do the authetification for the 4 Areas based on the Custom Membership Provider that I made ?

Comment: You need to look into roles.

Comment: I have checked em and I really don't know if it's wise to create a whole custom role provider, because it's a basic web site...

Comment: instead of creating a `custom role provider`, why don't you simply link `Roles` to `Areas` in your DB and `users` to `Roles`? Based on the `UserID`, you can determine their `Role` in and the `Area` they belong to. The will allow you to have a user who can access multiple `Areas`.